# Angular Slider snap to value

Tags: angular, mat-slider

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to make **snap** spots to different values inside the slider in Angular. Slider:

```
<mat-slider 
        min="0" max="90" step="1" tickinterval="auto" thumbLabel (input)="positionChanged(component, 'north.dx', $event.value)" (input)="positionChanged(component, 'north.dy', $event.value)"
></mat-slider>
```

I need to have three **snap** spots: `[33, 45, 90]`.

Link to documentation: [Angular mat-slider](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/)

Is there a way to do this inside the html? I hope someone is able to help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is not possible with current implementation of `mat-slider`

Comment: I believe the problem is, your step can't be calculated since it's not incremental, I think you can't do what you want with the current implementation of mat-slider

Comment: @Alann Alright, thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear of what you are trying to archieve here. can you elaborate more please?

Comment: @mHvNG try using this refreshless.com/nouislider

Comment: @SelakaN Just a slider (with angular) with snap spots to the values `33, 45, 90`. Thats it.

Comment: You basically need to capture the slider value  and if it is 33 or 45 or 90 take a snapshot right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
    <mat-slider #screen
      thumbLabel
      [displayWith]="formatLabel"
      tickInterval="1000"
      min="1"
      max="100000"></mat-slider>

    <div id="download">
      <img #canvas>
      <a #downloadLink></a>
    </div>
```

**In component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "slider-formatting-example",
  templateUrl: "slider-formatting-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["slider-formatting-example.css"]
})
export class SliderFormattingExample {
  @ViewChild('screen') screen: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('downloadLink') downloadLink: ElementRef;
  formatLabel(value: number) {
    if (value >= 1000) {
      console.log(value); // Your slider value is here
      if (value === 33) {
       html2canvas(this.screen.nativeElement).then(canvas => {
         this.canvas.nativeElement.src = canvas.toDataURL();
         this.downloadLink.nativeElement.href = 
         canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
         this.downloadLink.nativeElement.download = '33.png';
         this.downloadLink.nativeElement.click();
       });

      } else if (value === 45) {
      html2canvas(this.screen.nativeElement).then(canvas => {
         this.canvas.nativeElement.src = canvas.toDataURL();
         this.downloadLink.nativeElement.href = 
         canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
         this.downloadLink.nativeElement.download = '45.png';
         this.downloadLink.nativeElement.click();
       });
      } else if (value === 90) {
       html2canvas(this.screen.nativeElement).then(canvas => {
          this.canvas.nativeElement.src = canvas.toDataURL();
          this.downloadLink.nativeElement.href = 
          canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          this.downloadLink.nativeElement.download = 'marble-diagram.png';
          this.downloadLink.nativeElement.click();
       });
      }
      return Math.round(value / 1000) + "k";
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Please find the working stackblitz answer [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdwhd7). Now along with it you need to have the `html2canvas` library installed in the project Please find `html2canvas` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas). Its fairly straight forward to take snapshot in it. I'll share the stackblitz sample of taking snapshot with you [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-html2canvas-eggwcg?file=src/app/app.component.ts). What you need to do is programmtically take the snapshot if it is the having the value of `33,45,90` which I have done in the relevent `if` and `else if` blocks in the answer.